# Move TFS 2008 to Visual studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to move my TFS 2008 to Visual studio Team Services. Could you please tell me how to do that ? I saw few articles on this but it looks complicated to follow those steps.

Comment: Articles will likely be immensely more helpful than what we can post in one answer. You should try and find an article or guide, give it a go and then let us know what you get stuck on so that we can help you from there with a specific issue.

Comment: Thanks James. I think, i am not getting the right article. One article was https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ab87ebf-3fea-4e0c-80a2-d916b8a3a7bb/migrate-from-tfs-2008-to-visual-studio-online-formerly-known-as-team-foundatiion-service but that talks about moving from TFS 2010. I want specific way for moving from TFS 2008

Answer (score 2):

Since TFS 2008 (and indeed 2010) is no longer supported you Will likely find it difficult to find documentation. There are two tools to help you. One from OpsHub that can migrate you to Team Services and the other from the product team called TFS Integration Tools.

You should follow the ALM Rangers migration guide if you can, and use the OpsHub tool if you can't.

Comment: Thank you . I will try this. Only challenge is that , these tools migrate only TFS 2010

Comment: @Jayashree, you need to first upgrade TFS2008 to TFS2010, then run the OpsHub to migrate from TFS2010 to VSO, Check the "Scenario: Upgrading Team Foundation Server" chapter of TFS2010 installation guide for the details: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24337